# How are arguments passed to procs?

Tags: ruby

```
s = Proc.new {|x|x*2}
puts "proc:" + (s.call(5)).to_s

def foo(&a)
    a.call(5)
end
foo{|x| puts "foo:" + (x*3).to_s}
```

Running this program produces the output:

```
proc:10
foo:15
```

How does the value 3 from the foo block get passed to the proc? **I expected this output**:

```
proc:10
foo:10
```

**The proc is always called with the value 5 as the argument** because foo is defined as:

```
    a.call(5)
```

**Why is foo 15 in the output?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value 3 does not get passed to the proc because you're not passing `s` to `foo`.  You probably meant to write

```
foo {|x| puts "foo: #{s.call(x)}"}
```

or

```
puts "foo: #{foo(&s)}"
```

Additionally, these are equivalent:

```
def foo_1(x, &a)
  puts a.call(x)
end
def foo_2(x)
  puts yield(x)
end

foo_1(5, &s) #=> 10
foo_2(5, &s) #=> 10
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the block outputs `x*3` (as opposed to s which returns `x*2`) and `5*3` is 15.

Comment: When I call foo, what happens to a.call(5)? It's ignored? I thought it would be called and the output would be 10.

Comment: @uzo: `a` is the block `{|x| puts "foo:" + (x*3).to_s}`. This block multiplies the argument times 3. So when you call it with the argument 5, you get 5*3, which is 15.

Comment: Of course it's not ignored. a is called with the argument 5. a then outputs 5*3, which is 15.

Comment: @Chuck: a is block! Thanks. I mistakenly thought a.call(5) would invoke the Proc I had defined at the beginning, passing the foo block as an argument. Now that I think about it that doesn't make a whole lot of sense.